# The Peak of The X-Ray Bremsstrahlung Wavelength Curve

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays

This is probably not restricted to only Bremsstrahlung curves but other distribution curves as well. Is the peak the mode or mean wavelength produced? And more importantly why is approximately $1/3$ of the maximum the most likely wavelength observed?

Comment: maybe this will help http://folk.ntnu.no/floban/KJ%20%203055/X%20%20Ray/Bremsstrahlung.htm

Comment: The peak in what?